# Вытащить .class из EXE

Tags: java, отладка, exe, reverse-engineering, dump

У меня есть один файл и я хочу просмотреть содержимое классов. В дальнейшем я не хочу делать рабочий jar файл, просто просмотреть содержимое. Приложение было написанно на java и было упаковано
jar2exe. Всю информацию которую я находил вела меня на эту статью - [Reverse j2e](http://reverseengineeringtips.blogspot.com/2014/12/unpacking-jar2exe-21-extracting-jar.html?m=1). Упакованно на уровень 3.

Присутствует весь софт, есть общее понимание, но я не понимаю в каком моменте я допускаю ошибку.

Я нахожу значение в Resource Hacker.
[image: Resource Hacker]

Далее он использует OllyDbg, но OllyDbg не поддерживает x64 приложения, поэтому я использую x64dbg

Он входит в окно Enter expression из плагина OllyAdvanced, но в x64dbg я не нашёл такого плагина, поэтому использовал способ из [Видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UaGAv1y7hY0&list=PL6APFgZLMvQP-wRmbuOkC3B4xbLc1jhnX) 00:59. Получил это значение

[image: CffExplorer]

Захожу в dbg и запускаю софт там. Перехожу в окно с шестнадцатиричным значением и вписываю значение. Ставлю breakpoint.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запускаем программу и попадаем сюда [image: Тут]

Далее в статье описан проход по циклу и дамп памяти

Какой именно цикл и что дампить в память я не понимаю.
Может быть допустил ошибку в прошлых шагах?

Спасибо заранее за помощь

Comment: Думаю в РУ сегменте SO, на такой вопрос сложно получить ответ, попробуйте продублировать на англ версию, с гораздо больших охватом аудитории)

Comment: @wigravy
  
Спасибо, сейчас займусь)